# Annotation shows callout instead of starting the drag and drop action

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit

I am using Swift on iOS 8.x. I have a few annotations on my map(kit) with a custom image. Now I want the user to be able to use drag and drop with the pins. This already works, but each time, the user clicks (and hold) on an annotation, the callout will be shown instead of the drag animation. After the callout is visible an I click on the annotation again, I am able to drag and drop it around.

How can I change the behavior so that I simply don't show the callout but start the drag and drop if the user presses and hold on the annotation?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In your mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! :

```
    var annotView:MyAnnotationView? = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("AnnotViewIdentifier") as? MyAnnotationView

                if let trueAnnotView  = annotView
                {
                    // Assegno l'annotazione
                    trueAnnotView.annotation = annotation;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Creo una vista se non disponibile
                    annotView = MyAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "AnnotViewIdentifier")
                    annotView?.canShowCallout = false
                    annotView?.draggable = true
                    annotView?.enabled = true
                }
                return annotView
```

Comment: No, This just disables the callout. I don't want to disable the callout, I simply don't want it to show up if the user actually wants to drag and drop the pin around

Comment: You can change the canShowCallout property in mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, didChangeDragState newState: MKAnnotationViewDragState, fromOldState oldState: MKAnnotationViewDragState) when the newState is equal to .Starting